# In react, how to store object in array and iterate the array index by 1?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, iterator

I have a page that displays multiple boxes and each box belongs to a specific company. Each company has multiple projects and each project has multiple releases.

**Box 1:**
Company Name / Project Name / Release Name

**Box 2:**
Company Name / Project Name / Release Name

I have a state defined as such:

```
this.state = {
  companies: [],
  projects: [],
  releases: [],
  activeProjects: []
}
```

And here, I am fetching all the data from the database:

```
componentWillMount() {
  getCompanys().then(companies => {
    const projectPromises = companies.map((company) => {
      getProjects(company).then(projects => {
        const releasePromises = projects.map((project) => {
          return getReleases(project).then(releases => {
            if(projects.length > 0 || releases > 0) {
              this.setState({
                companies: companies,
                projects: projects,
                releases: releases
              });
            }
          })
        })
      })
    });
  })
}
```

which comes back with the following data:

```
Companys:  (2) [{…}, {…}]0: {_id: {…}, company_name: "IBM", …}
Projects:  [{…}]0: {_id: {…}, project_name: "Project 101", …}
Releases:  (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]0: {_id: {…}, release_name: "Release 103", …}
```

I am getting 2 companies, 1 project, and 3 releases.

If I wanted to store each of my company, project, and release into my **activeProjects** array, how would I achieve the following?

```
activeProjects: [
  {
    company: ,
    project: ,
    release: 
  },
  {
    company: ,
    project: ,
    release: 
  },
]
```

Can someone please help me out?

I want my end result to be someting like this:

```
activeProjects.map((project, index) => {
  return(
    **Box 1**
    IBM / Project 101 / Release Name goes here

    **Box 2**
    Facebook / Project 102 / Release Name goes here
  )
});
```

Comment: Can you give us anymore info on the relation between companies, projects, and releases? Like, do projects have a reference to the company they belong to? Is there any indicator of what's the latest release (assuming you want the latest release displayed in the boxes)?

Comment: @bwalshy- in DB, each company has a field of projects which is of type an array that holds the project id. Likewise, each project has a field called releases which is of type an array that holds an object id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend structuring your data in the desired format from the beginning. What I mean by this is rather than splitting your companies, projects, and releases into separate arrays in your state, just keep them nested from the start.

(Also from what I can tell from your code, you are overwriting the projects and releases each time so you are only left with projects for the last company and releases for the last project.)

**1.** First structure state like this:

```
state = {
    companies: [],
    activeProjects: []
}
```

**2.** Then rework your `componentWillMount` method to be something like this (also I would recommend using `async`/`await` instead of callbacks for ease of readability).

```
async componentWillMount() {
    const companies = await getCompanies();
    for (const company of companies) {
        company.projects = await getProjects(company);
        for (const project of company.projects) {
            project.releases = await getP
        }
    }

    this.setState({ companies });
}
```

Here is a version that is a bit more complicated but more efficient because it can work on multiple companies/projects asynchronously rather than waiting for responses for each call before moving on:

```
async componentWillMount() {
    const companies = await getCompanies();
    const nestedCompanies = await Promise.all(companies.map(async company => {
        const projects = await getProjects(company);
        const nestedProjects = await Promise.all(projects.map(async project => {
            const releases = await getReleases(project);
            return {
                ...project,
                releases
            }
        }));
        return {
            ...company,
            projects: nestedProjects
        }
    }));

    this.setState({ companies: nestedCompanies });
}
```

Now your state will look like this:

```
{
    companies: [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: 'IBM',
            projects: [
                {
                    id: 1,
                    name: 'Project 101',
                    releases: [
                        {
                            name: 'Release Name'
                        },
                        // and so on
                    ]
                },
                // and so on
            ]
        },
        // and so on
    ]
}
```

**3.** Now looping through the data in companies should be fairly simple. You can do something like this:

```
const activeProjects = this.state.companies.map(company => {
    return company.projects.map(project => {
        return project.releases.map(release => {
            return `${company.name} / ${project.name} / ${release.name}`;
        });
    }).reduce((acc, e) => acc.concat(e), []);
}).reduce((acc, e) => acc.concat(e), []);
```

The above code will result in `activeProjects` being an array of strings, each of which have the format `'IBM / Project 101 / Release Name'`. For this last step you could instead return some component like:

```
<Box company={ company.name } project={ project.name } release={ release.name }/>,
```

depending on how your project is structured.

Comment: Henry, this is awesome! Thank you so much for providing this, really appreciate it!